# Where does the business logic go in WCF Data service using entity framework?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services, odata

I was looking at how you can create a WCF data service around an entity framework context and you can consume it as an EF context as well.

[Creating an OData API for StackOverflow including XML and JSON in 30 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx)

I really just started looking at this, but I was wondering where would the business logic go? As a service I would expect that you couldn't just freely add/delete etc without it having some validation.

If I wrote an MVC app to consume this service, how would I best implement business logic. Not simple property level validation that you could do with attributes, but more complex stuff that needs to check the data store first etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a custom data service provider [(msdn link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg191846).  They're quite powerful and give you full control over all of your reading/writing logic.

For example I wrote one that enforces our licensing logic in the update provider.

Answer (score 2):

You can put some in the Data Service class, but you are limited as to what you can and can't do there. And then of course you can put some in the client above the service, but that's not ideal either.

I've only spent a few weeks with WCF Data Services but you highlight (one of) the big problems with it - lack of flexibility. It's fantastic for rapid development and banging out LOB applications, but anything with a deliberate design is very difficult to implement.  I needed to include objects in my entity model simply to allow them to be exposed through the service, and I had huge headaches just trying to extend those classes with a simple property.

I'd only recommend using WCF Data Services for trivially simple applications that needed extremely fast development - a one or two day development cycle, for example. Anything else is worth doing thoroughly with regular WCF services, writing your own data layer and so on.

Comment: (I sincerely intend for this to be constructive feedback.) While I wholeheartedly agree with the fact that there is a lack of flexibility in WCF Data Services, I think characterizations like "forced to expose your database entities through to the client" demonstrate an incomplete understanding of what WCF DS is all about. The custom provider, as Jason mentioned, allows you to do pretty much anything you want to do. I would love to see Microsoft OR the community put together a provider that allows for more extensibility than the in-box providers.

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT thanks for the feedback. As I noted I've only spent a few weeks with it Data Services and just highlighted my experience. The particular sentence you highlighted doesn't read as I intended and I'm changing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your specific needs, it sounds like Web API might be a good fit. Web API may never get the full range of OData support that WCF Data Services has, but it does make certain things easier (like adding business logic). I'm quite confident that Web API's initial support for OData will cover a significant number of use cases, and that support will grow over time.

Answer (score 0):

While a custom data provider will most certainly do about anything you want and may well be a great solution for you if you have a complex architecture, I wasn't really thrilled when I attempted to save back through the client and found out I had to implement my the IUpdatable Interface as part of my Context.(I was attempting to build a repository pattern out of my context and DataService).

I'm sure it's very useful for many people, but I really only needed the functionality the EntityProvider already contained and didn't have the time in my project schedule to figure the Iupdatable piece of the custom provider out, so my team, specifically [Geoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097/geoff) , stuck with the Entity Provider and used Change and Query Interceptors to route the DataService requests through our Business Logic classes on the server. It provides a central point of control. We used these to provide security checks, run  calculations and other operations on Insert/Update, etc. Turned out great. You can also use service methods as another way to provide specific business logic functions to your clients.